# Create new array from a defined array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repeat

If I have an array, `a = [1,2,3,4,2,1]`, how can I create another array, which shows the number of times each number in array a has been repeated, for example from array a then the new array would be `b = [2,2,1,1]`? Is this possible using a command in the NumPy library?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191/929999

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can do this:

```py
[a.count(i + 1) for i in range(max(a))]
```

More generally, look into [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain there are many ways to do that. Here's one:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,2,1]

count = {}
for item in a: 
    count[item] = count.get(item, 0) + 1

[v for k,v in count.items()]
```

Result:

```
[2, 2, 1, 1]
```